# Can't set up phpmyadmin on Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, macos-high-sierra

I've been some hours trying to set up phpmyadmin in my MacBook Pro, and I get to have in running in localhost, but when it comes to filling the username and password, I get some errors, usually related to SQL. I was wondering if there is any tutorial to follow so I can set it up properly.

Thank you,
Álvaro.

Comment: It would be most helpful if you could paste those errors here.

Comment: Thank you! After introducing the user and password it says: "Cannot log in to the MySQL server" and "mysql_real_connect(): (HY000/2001): No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

When you're using the default 'host' value in phpMyAdmin, it tries to connect via socket connection (`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';` is the default, unless you've explicitly set it in `config.inc.php`). On Mac OS, for some reason PHP and MySQL don't agree about the default location of the socket file.

There are several easy solutions, but for two of them you must first determine the actual path to the socket. The easiest way is to get to the MySQL command prompt. Open 'Terminal' in the Applications -> Utilities folder, then type `mysql -u root -p` and when prompted, enter your MySQL root password (the default is usually blank). At the MySQL prompt, type `status;` and you'll see a list of several connection-related settings. Look for one like

> UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

This is the path to the socket. Yours will almost certainly be different than this.

Now, about those ways to fix this:

1. Change the default socket in PHP. Open the PHP configuration file (likely php.ini) in your favorite text editor and add the correct path to the line `mysqli.default_socket =`. This change will affect any PHP script using the default system socket path.
2. Change the socket only for phpMyAdmin. Open the phpMyAdmin configuration file (config.inc.php) in your favorite text editor. Edit or add the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';` with the correct path.
3. Switch the connection type to TCP networking. Again, edit the phpMyAdmin configuration file (config.inc.php) and edit or add the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`. This will tell phpMyAdmin to use the TCP networking connection method instead of sockets. Note that your MySQL instances may not listen for incoming TCP connections by default and that your MySQL user root@localhost is not the same as root@127.0.0.1 or root@%.

You should only need one of those solutions, not all three.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but I was still unable to set it up properly, so I am using SequelPro now. I think I maybe modified some line in the phpmyadmin config, still don't know. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the port number. You can use port no 8080 or 3306. It worked for me.