# phpMyAdmin mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm tring to set up phpmyadmin on my mac, mysql already running on my mac, but I got mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused error, anyone knows how to fix it, thanks

---

[image: this is the phpmyadimin page]

---

[image: mysql is working on my mac]

--------------------------------------------------------

config.inc.php file:

```
<?php
/*
 * Generated configuration file
 * Generated by: phpMyAdmin 5.0.4 setup script
 * Date: Tue, 20 Oct 2020 11:36:42 +0000
 */

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: 127.0.0.1 [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'C0DH:ogx;5K1W`tteE3T%xL`0TzHYSD~';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't set up phpmyadmin on Mac OS High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50045935/cant-set-up-phpmyadmin-on-mac-os-high-sierra)

Comment: Try to log in from CLI:
mysql -u root -p after MySQL> write following command : SELECT host, user from mysql.user; write back what you got.

Comment: Is the docker copy of MySQL running through a different Port?

Answer (score 1):

firstly stop MySQL and in terminal enter:

```
cd
cd /var
sudo mkdir mysql
sudo chmod 755 mysql
cd mysql
ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock mysql.sock
```

finally restart MySQL

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you login as `root` without a password, be sure to set this in the `config.inc.php` file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Otherwise, this worked for me to solve your original problem:

Locate the main database config file. In my case I'm using Mariadb, so the file I located was `/etc/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf`

Make these two changes:

1. Comment out `skip-networking`

```
#skip-networking
```

2. Uncomment `bind-address`

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

You'll then need to restart your database server.
Should be able to login using phpMyAdmin after that.